# Snap Scroll in depth with JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to go deep with Scroll Snap and your help.

I need to achieve 3 effects:

- Able to be draggable
- Able to scroll smoothly to an anchor
- Able to Trigger a simple animation like changing color when content it's snapped

You can use CSS / JavaScript / jQuery / etc... to achieve the desired effects. Here's the snippet with no results so far:

```css
        a, span {
            position: absolute
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .child {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #F0F0F0;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: -4px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .label {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius: 25%;
            background-color: white;
            margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
        }

        .label > h1 {
            font-size: 80px;
            padding-left: calc(50% - 22px);
            padding-top: calc(50% - 60px);
        }

        .container {
            width: 402px;
            height: 410px;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            margin: 10vh auto 0 auto;
        }

#snap-scroll-container {
            -webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
            scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
            -webkit-scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
            scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="snap-scroll-container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="label">
      <h1>1</h1>
      <a href="#3">I must smooth scroll to 3!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="label">
      <h1>2</h1>
      <span>I must change color when snaps!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="child">
    <div class="label">
      <h1>3</h1>
      <span>Scroll must be draggable too!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your help is really appreciated!